# Queue object shared between threads and objects in separate modules

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, queue, priority-queue

I am trying to build a system that will crawl a remote server continuously and download new files locally. I want crawling and downloading to be split into separate objects, and separate threads. To keep track of files found on the server and which still needs to be downloaded, I will use a PriorityQueue.

Because the system will be larger later with more tasks added, I will need a main module that sits on top and I need to initiate the PriorityQueue in the main module. But I have a problem on how to share this PriorityQueue between the main module and the crawler.

Here is the code below, ignoring the download part for now as it doesn't play into the problem yet, as I can't figure out how to make the Crawler object "see" the queue object created in main.py.

main.py

```
import crawler
import threading
from queue import PriorityQueue
class Watchdog(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = PriorityQueue

    def setup(self):
        self.crawler    = crawler.Crawler()

    def run(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.crawler.crawl(), args=(<pysftp connection>,))
        t1.daemon=True
        t2.daemon=True
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
```

crawler.py

```
import pysftp
class Crawler(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    def crawl(self):
        callbacks = pysftp.WTCallbacks()
        self.connection.walktree(rootdir, fcallback=callbacks.file_cb, dcallback=callbacks.dir_cb, ucallback=callbacks.unk_cb)
        for fpath in callbacks.flist:
            with queue.mutex:
                if not fpath in queue.queue:
                    queue.put(os.path.getmtime(fpath), fpath)
```

The problem is that I can not figure out how I can make the queue object I create in main.py to be reachable and shared in crawler.py. When I add the download task, it should also be able to see the queue object, and I need the queue to be synced over all modules, so that when a new file is added by crawler, the downloader will immediately see that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiprocessing module. Check the doc at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

You could also use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)